# C++ memory model char vs word, concurrency? From Stroustrup book

Tags: c++

Stroustrup gives the following example in *C++ 4th Ed Page 1193*. My question is with a concurrent program using two thread, one for `f()` and the other for `g()` and Stroustrup's statement that:

> if a linker allocated c and b in the same word in memory and (like most modern hardware)",

what happens to variables `c` and `b`?

It's my understanding on some hardware a word is 2 bytes and both variables are contained in it, one thread may overwrite another's `char`.

Stroustrup further states the following:

> Without a well-defined and reasonable memory model, thread 1 might
> read the word containing b and c, change c, and write the word back
> into memory. At the same time, thread 2 could do the same with b.
> Then, whichever thread managed to read the word first and whichever
> thread man- aged to write its result back into memory last would
> determine the result. We might get 10, 01, or 11 (but not 00). The
> memory model saves us from such chaos; we get 11. The reason that 00
> can not happen is that the initializations of b and c are done (by
> the compiler or the linker) before either thread starts.

My confusion is, for the solution to this, does the C++ linker place `c` in one 2-byte memory address and `b` in another?

```
// thread 1
char c = 0;
void f()
{
    c = 1;
    int x = c;
}

char b = 0;
void g()
{
    b = 1;
    int y = b;
}
```

Comment: "*since a word is 2 bytes*" Citation needed.

Comment: removed x86 and used 2 bytes as an example size

Comment: @NicolBolas -- Microsoft said so in their standard. It must be so.

Comment: @Scheff -- I was being facetious.

Comment: @Andy The term _word_ was used before Microsoft gave it a specific meaning in its OS/API. Thereby, the word size is often H/W dependent - also used as "machine word size" - the quanitity processed at once. [Word (Wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_(computer_architecture))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The point Stroustrup is making is that the C++ implementation is required to do *whatever* is necessary on the particular hardware to make things work as the memory model requires. What that may be dependent on the particulars of the hardware. A particular cache architecture might allow two values within the same "word" to be modified concurrently from different threads. If a particular cache architecture cannot do that, then it is the implementation's job to make sure that each individual C++ object still behaves correctly, in accord with the memory model. That may require inserting padding, or doing special write operations or whatever.

Comment: Thanks, so in this example with 2 threads, one can assume the linker or some other underlying logic would ensure these two variables are mutually exclusive in terms of access?  I.e. to prevent the issue with concurrent threads?

Comment: @notaorb The part of the compiler generating the code is written for a specific CPU and architecture. (This is often called back-end, and there are compilers with multiple back-ends like gcc.) The authors of the code-emitting compiler part have to care about CPU/architecture specifics. I believe this is part of the compiler as well not (or not only) of the linker. FYI: [Compiler Design](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_architecture.htm)